# legacy jquery code does not work with 3.1 v

Tags: javascript, jquery

My below script worked  fine with an older version of jQuery but will *not* run with 3.1 any suggestions? *Below is the code.*

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('div').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay((i + 1) * 3000).fadeOut(1000);
   });
});
```

---

For instance; the below JSfiddle is updated using jQuery 3.1. It does not run.

-> http://jsfiddle.net/hh42R/138/

But when you change that to **jQuery 1.6 within the same fiddle, it works fine** without problem.

Comment: In which way(s) is it no longer working?

Comment: _It's just completely dead._ Sorry, this doesn't really clarify anything.  Not working, completely dead, doing nothing, etc. won't help with reproduction or corrective measures.

Comment: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Comment: @CamC. That's not a good way to get help.

Comment: who downvoted ? without knowing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the `load()` method. In jQuery 3.x this is no longer an event handler.

Instead you need to use `on('load', fn)`:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('div').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i + 1) * 3000).fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #C00;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ref: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Comment: Thanks so much, I guess I should have known that via the downvotes. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just for future reference, I think the downvotes were for the vague question, not the nature of the problem.